# TypeError: modules[moduleId] is undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox, jenkins, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run jasmine unit testing with Jenkins using Firefox browser on Linux and I keep having this behavior:

```
[32m02 08 2017 08:16:26.443:INFO [Firefox 50.0.0 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0)]:  [39mConnected on socket /#KYlvgi9JYtXnD1jZAAAB with id manual-931
Firefox 50.0.0 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: modules[moduleId] is undefined
  at http://52.5.4.155:9876/_karma_webpack_/inline.bundle.js:55
Firefox 50.0.0 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: modules[moduleId] is undefined
  at http://52.5.4.155:9876/_karma_webpack_/inline.bundle.js:55


[33m02 08 2017 08:21:27.750:WARN [Firefox 50.0.0 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0)]:  [39mDisconnected (1 times)
Firefox 50.0.0 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) ERROR
Disconnectedundefined
Firefox 50.0.0 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) ERROR
Disconnectedundefined
```

The exception is on this Line of code:

```
// Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
```

I research a lot about the issue, but I couldn't find any solution. Is there anyone that can help me to solve it.

Comment: found any solution? I have the same problem

Comment: It could be the reason of some missing comma or brackets. Common places are route array, styles array, etc

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and found that in Karma.conf.js, I was using wrong configuration for "files" as

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
        '../../ClientApp/dist/vendor.js',
        './boot-tests.ts'
    ],
```

Modified this to target only files which contain unit tests as

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
        '../../ClientApp/**/*.spec.ts'
    ],
```

and now I don't get this error. Though something else going wrong in my tests so getting other errors but seems this specific issue resolved.

Comment: Answer given above was not 100% correct but it has something to do with your files included in Karma.conf.js. I was also able to solve the issue by using files: [
            '../../wwwroot/dist/app.js',
            '../../wwwroot/dist/vendor.js',
            '../../ClientApp/**/*.spec.ts'
        ]. It seems app.js declaring the Modules used in vendor.js and I load app.js before other files, Note order of files matter.